# OpenLayers 3.10 - GetIndex / SetIndex

Tags: javascript, cartography, openlayers, openlayers-2, mapping

I am a complete beginner to OpenLayers and web mapping in general. I am trying to change the layers' order of my map by modifying the layers' index value, but I cannot get my code to work.

Any hint on what the problem is?

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Simple example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/ol3/css/ol.css" type="text/css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/samples.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="doSwitch();">Switch layer</button>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="../assets/ol3/js/ol.js"> </script> 
<script>
    /* Layers */
    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'}),
    });
    var satLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'}),
    });

    /* View and map */
    var view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-1.8118500054456526, 52.4431409750608], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 6
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
    });

    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    map.addLayer(satLayer);
    map.setView(view);

    /* Switch function */
    function doSwitch(){
        var satIndex = map.getLayerIndex(satLayer);
        if (satIndex === 1) {
            map.setLayerIndex(osmLayer, 1);
            map.setLayerIndex(satLayer, 0);
        } else {
            map.setLayerIndex(osmLayer, 0);
            map.setLayerIndex(satLayer, 1);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Edit

This works on OL 3.10.

```
        /* Switch function */
    function doSwitch(){
        var satIndex = satLayer.getZIndex();
        if (satIndex === 1) {
            osmLayer.setZIndex(1);
            satLayer.setZIndex(0);
        } else {
            osmLayer.setZIndex(0);
            satLayer.setZIndex(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing OpenLayers 2 and OpenLayers 3 code. OpenLayers 3 is not backwards compatible, and you should not expect its API to equal OpenLayers 2.

In OpenLayers 3, layer render ordering is controlled by the zIndex property and the [`setZIndex`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#setZIndex) method of each layer.